# React, ES6+7 ajax call not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been mind boggled by this since yesterday. I can't seem to render the data from local server through json-server into my React code with **ES6+7** syntax. I did try it with the **ES5** way too and gave me no result.

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

const source = "http://localhost:3000/";

    class App extends Component {

  state = { authors: [] };

  static defaultProps = {
    source: ''
  };

  static propTypes() {
    source: React.PropTypes.string
  };

  loadAuthors() {
      fetch(source)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ authors: data }))
    .catch(err => console.error(source, err.toString()))
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadAuthors()
  }

  render() {
    const renderData = this.state.authors.map(function(author) {
      return (
        <div>
        <p>author.id</p>
        <p>author.firstName</p>
        <p>author.lastName</p>
        </div>
      )
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          Welcome to the react starter!
        </h1>
        <h1>
          {renderData}
        </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**JSON source**

```
{
  authors: [
    {
      id: "zarghon-shah",
      firstName: "Zarghon",
      lastName: "Shah"
    },
    {
      id: "khpalwalk-pashtun",
      firstName: "Khpalwalk",
      lastName: "Pashtun"
    },
    {
      id: "sazinda-khudai",
      firstName: "Sazinda",
      lastName: "Khudai"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you get an error in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to put JSX curly braces around your references to "author", so that the interpolation happens correctly:

```
const renderData = this.state.authors.map(function(author) {
  return (
    <div>
    <p>{author.id}</p>
    <p>{author.firstName}</p>
    <p>{author.lastName}</p>
    </div>
  )
});
```

Otherwise you're just writing out the literal strings "author.id", etc.